# Azure Functions and Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

Let's say I have a Node.js app I want to build with a `TimerTrigger` on Azure Functions.

What would be the best way to develop it? I already tried setting the `NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `8.7.0` but it's still giving me problems like incorrect syntax when I know the Node can handle it.

Does anyone have any experience building Node.js apps on Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version of the function runtime, you cannot choose the Node version. But in the next version, which is currently in Preview, you can and will be able to pick 8.7.0. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions for details.

Comment: Thank you @David_Ebbo. So, even if I set `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to even... `8.5.0`, then it will still run the `6.5.0` node build? Because i am trying to execute async code and it's giving me runtime errors. Did I get that right?

Comment: Correct, it will have no effect on the v1 runtime

Comment: Bummer, so that means, if even I set my function app setting `runtime version` set to BETA and my `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `8.5.0` , that my Node.js code will stil fail? Just a matter of waiting at the moment, it seems? (Thank you.)

Comment: Let me know if I got anything wrong, @David_Ebbo. So, at the moment, `BETA` version still cannot run advanced Node.js with featueeres like async and whatnot.

Comment: If you set your runtime version to Beta (which is 2.x), you should be able to target Node 8.7. You can verify that by adding something like this in your function: `context.log('Node version: ' + process.version);`. The key is: start by focusing on the node **version** it's using rather than looking at what features work. If you're having issues with a specific feature, please start a separate question.